# Unix - Replace column value inside while loop

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have comma separated (sometimes tab) text file as below:

**parameters.txt:**

```
STD,ORDER,ORDER_START.xml,/DML/SOL,Y
STD,INSTALL_BASE,INSTALL_START.xml,/DML/IB,Y
```

with below code I try to loop through the file and do something

```
while read line; do
if [[ $1 =  "$(echo "$line" | cut -f 1)" ]] && [[ "$(echo "$line" | cut -f 5)" = "Y"  ]] ; then
//do something...
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
// code to replace the final flag
fi
fi
done < <text_file_path>
```

I wanted to update the last column of the file to `N` if the above operation is successful, however below approaches are not working for me:

1. `sed 's/$f5/N/'`
2. `'$5=="Y",$5=N;{print}'`
3. `$(echo "$line" | awk '$5=N')`

Update: Few considerations which need to be considered to give more clarity which i missed at first, apologies!

1. The parameters file may contain lines with last field flag as "N" as well.
2. Final flag needs to be update only if "//do something" code has successfully executed.
3. After looping through all lines i.e, after exiting "while loop" flags for all rows to be set to "Y"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with bash:

```
(
IFS=,
while read -ra fields; do
    if [[ ${fields[0]} == "$1" ]] && [[ ${fields[4]} == "Y" ]]; then
        # do something
        fields[4]="N"
    fi
    echo "${fields[*]}"
done < file | sponge file
)
```

I run that in a subshell so the effects of altering IFS are localized.

This uses `sponge` to write back to the same file. You need the `moreutils` package to use it, otherwise use

```
done < file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

---

Perhaps a bit simpler, less bash-specific

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    case $line in 
        "$1",*,Y) 
            # do something
            line="${line%Y}N"
            ;; 
    esac
    echo "$line"
done < file
```

Comment: I tried this but after the execution the lines which already has "N" as the flag are missed out completely in the final file, perhaps i should have mentioned that file may contain lines with "N" as well, if its already "N" it should ignore it. Edited the question

Comment: I added else condition to your code and result is as expected,thanks.

Answer (score 3):

perhaps invert the operations do processing in `awk`.

```
$ awk -v f1="$1" 'BEGIN             {FS=OFS=","}
                  f1==$1 && $5=="Y" { // do something
                                      $5="N"}1'  file
```

not sure what "do something" operation is, if you need to call another command/script it's possible as well.

Comment: thanks, I have to change the flag only if "do something" command has successfully executed so the order would be as in code

Answer (score 0):

To replace `,N` at the end of the line(`$`) with `,Y`:

```
sed 's/,N$/,Y/' file
```